# Throws keyword can't be used with run method of threads

Tags: java

I read that throws keyword can't be used with run method of threads.I wish to know if its a design fault or is there a genuine reason for not allowing this.

Comment: How ware you going to catch exception thrown by thread from `run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that there's no-one to catch the exception, except for any catch-all handlers you might  register with your `Thread` or the containing `ThreadGroup`.

Note that you can still throw a `RuntimeException`, which will end up at the aforementioned handler.

(The same reasoning can be used for `run()`s return value of `void` by the way.)

Comment: That is not always true.  The process involved in catching a thread exception is handled at the OS level.  This actually happens more often then not as you are waiting on an I/O operation (thread interrupts).  In that case, the exception is that the file hasn't completed coming off the disk yet.  Technically JButtons throw an exception as well so big brother compiler and operating system are always around to handle anything that happens, the default operation though is to just end the program that caused it.

Comment: @MattWestlake Of course something always handles the exception, but the idea of checked exceptions is built around the assumption that there's a matching catch block that is designed to deal with that type of exception specifically.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.run()` is declared to not throw a checked exception for the same reason that the `static main(String args)` in a Java console app does not throw a checked exception—there's no way for you to write code that would catch it. (Both methods are generally called by the Java runtime environment, not by your code.) Note that either method can still throw an *unchecked* exception (`RuntimeException`, `Error`, and their subclasses). The Java runtime environment will handle those (generally in a not-very-graceful way).

Comment: A `main()` method may declare any exception to be thrown though.

Comment: @biziclop - True, although `main` with an exception compiles because (as a static method) it is not overriding anything. It also works at run time because the virtual machine ignores any `throws` clause when it resolves the required `static main(String[])` method. Nevertheless, according to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) and the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.6), `main` is not declared to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well `Runnable's` `run()` method **can't return, nor can throw any Checked Exception**... Most probably the Designers of Java thought that its not worth throwing the exception on a separate thread which is mostly a separate process back...

But later from **Java 1.5** `Callable<T>` inteface came with `call()` method which **can return and throw a checked exception...**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the calling context cannot get the return value or exception, as it now runs in new context (that is the all meaning of new thread). however you can use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler ()

Answer (score 0):

Run itself does not throw an exception.  All you are doing when you call .start() (call the run() function) is tell the program to continue going down a path with a new thread.  The function calls and everything inside the run() function can throw an exception.  run() itself has no possible run time errors.  If there is a run time error it is because your process explorer, handler, or some OS level problem occurred and then it is nothing that can be handled by your program.